# Find the Energy release in this Nuclear Reaction (Fission)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, energy-conservation

Plutonium undergoes nuclear fission according to the equation below: 
[image]

The value of $x=3$. The question is to estimate the energy released in this reaction. I know the Binding Energy per nucleon ($B$) of the all the reactants and the Products. So at first glance, I wrote down the following expression:

$E_{released}=E_{reactants}-E_{products}$

Now $$E_{reactants}=239*B_{pu}+1*B_{n}$$ $$E_{products}=91*B_{sr}+146*B_{ba}+3*B_{n}$$

When I computed the expression I ended up with a negative expression which is definitely incorrect. In the answer, the author has not accounted for the neutrons' Binding Energy. Why is this so?

@Lewis suggested that the neutrons are free particles. How does one go on to determine which particle is free or not?

Comment: Because the original neutron and the final 3 neutrons are not bound.  They are free particles.

Comment: Could you please elaborate..

Comment: Binding energy is the difference between the rest energy ($mc^2$) of a composite particle and the sum of the rest energies of its constituents.  Although neutrons are composites (made of 3 quarks), they cannot be decomposed into 3 free quarks, s0 when not bound in a nucleus they (neutrons) are free particles.  In the fission reaction you describe, the 3 (approximately) neutrons in the final state were part of the 239-Pu nucleus prior to the reaction, but in the final state they are free neutrons.

Comment: So consider the following reaction: $N^{14}_7+He^{4}_2 ---->O^{17}_8+H^1_1$. Here Nitrogen, Helium, Oxygen can be decomposed and Hydrogen can be decomposed into a proton and an electron. So in this case to find the minimum energy required for the reaction to take place one must account for all the rest energies since there are no free particles. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Technically correct, but the binding energy of the electron to the proton is very small compared to the nuclear binding so you would not be far wrong to treat the proton as a free particle.

Answer (score 0):

**Shot Form**

The information about where you got your values ​​from was not appropriate for the task. In addition, a few things are missing in the reaction equation. Aka you're $100\%$ right.

---

---

**Detailed Form**

In nuclides, protons are bound to neutrons by binding energy. This binding energy in turn also has a mass equivalent, which is why when measuring the mass of a nuclide we do not measure the sum of the masses of the nucleons, but rather the total energy and mass of the nuclide when it is at rest. We call this difference the *[mass defect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Mass_defect)*.

Knowing this we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
{\rm{_{94}^{239}Pu} + \rm{_{0}^{1}n}} &\to {\rm{_{38}^{91}Sr} + \rm{_{56}^{146}Ba} + 3 \cdot \rm{_{0}^{1}n}} + E_{\text{released}}\\
m_{\rm{_{94}^{239}Pu}} + m_{\rm{_{0}^{1}n}} &= m_{\rm{_{38}^{91}Sr}} + m_{\rm{_{56}^{146}Ba}} + 3 \cdot m_{\rm{_{0}^{1}n}} + E_{\text{released}} \cdot c^{-2}\\
\end{align*}
$$
$$
\begin{align*}
E_{\text{released}} \cdot c^{-2} &= {m_{\rm{_{94}^{239}Pu}} + m_{\rm{_{0}^{1}n}} - m_{\rm{_{38}^{91}Sr}} - m_{\rm{_{56}^{146}Ba}} - 3 \cdot m_{\rm{_{0}^{1}n}}}\\
E_{\text{released}} &= \left( {m_{\rm{_{94}^{239}Pu}} + m_{\rm{_{0}^{1}n}} - m_{\rm{_{38}^{91}Sr}} - m_{\rm{_{56}^{146}Ba}} - 3 \cdot m_{\rm{_{0}^{1}n}}} \right) \cdot c^{2}\\
\end{align*}
$$

From Wikipedia's list of isotopes of the elements ([isotopes of plutonium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_plutonium), [isotopes of strontium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_strontium) and [isotopes of barium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_barium)) we can now use the nuclide masses ($m_{\rm{_{94}^{239}Pu}} = 239.0521634(20) ~\mathrm{Da}$, $m_{\rm{_{38}^{91}Sr}} = 90.910203(5) ~\mathrm{Da}$, $m_{\rm{_{56}^{146}Ba}} = 148.94258(21) ~\mathrm{Da}$) and $m_{n} \approx 1.0086710869\dots ~\mathrm{Da}$). But wait a minute! The mass of the products is higher than the reactants, so there must be something wrong somewhere in our source!

---

If we look, we see that the mass of $\rm{_{56}^{146}Ba}$ was theoretically calculated outdated and the value is not up-to-date. The calculated value is way too high! In reality it is $\approx 145.93036 ~\rm{Da}$. This means that the mass of the reactants is again higher than the mass of the products and almost everything is fine again, apart from the fact that the reaction equation is not complete because, for example, the neutrinos that are released are missing.

Let's do the whole calculation again from the beginning:
$$
\begin{align*}
E_{\text{released}} &= \left( {m_{\rm{_{94}^{239}Pu}} + m_{\rm{_{0}^{1}n}} - m_{\rm{_{38}^{91}Sr}} - m_{\rm{_{56}^{146}Ba}} - 3 \cdot m_{\rm{_{0}^{1}n}}} \right) \cdot c^{2}\\
E_{\text{released}} &= \left( {m_{\rm{_{94}^{239}Pu}} - m_{\rm{_{38}^{91}Sr}} - m_{\rm{_{56}^{146}Ba}} - 2 \cdot m_{\rm{_{0}^{1}n}}} \right) \cdot c^{2}\\
E_{\text{released}} &\approx \left( 239.05216 - 90.9102 - 145.93036 - 2 \cdot 1.00866491 \right) ~\mathrm{Da} \cdot c^{2}\\
E_{\text{released}} &\approx 0.1943 ~\mathrm{Da} \cdot c^{2}\\
\end{align*}
$$
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
E_{\text{released}} &\approx 181 ~\mathrm{MeV}\\
\end{align*}
$}$$

However, this value is smaller than the value found when researching the actual energy released. Reasons for this are, among others, that the equation completely neglects the neutrinos, antineutrinos, the decay products, delayed gamma quanta and the energy released by radiative capture of prompt neutrons, which all happens by the way.

If we add the other energies that the equation ignores, we get in average $218.6 ~\mathrm{MeV}$. We often only find the number $207.1 ~\mathrm{MeV}$ when ignoring the energy released by radiative capture of prompt neutrons.

---

If you're looking for reliable data, whether it's physics, mathematics, chemistry, computer science, ... I can only recommend Wolfram|Alpha. Wolfram|Alpha doesn't just do the math for you, it also searches for the values ​​and gives you the sources for them. My Wolfram|Alpha input for this equation was `(239Pu mass - 2*neutron mass- 91Sr atomic mass-146Ba mass)*speed of light^2` aka:

[image: wolfram input]

Comment: In your intermediate step where you use and then discard a mass of $\sim149\,\rm Da$ for Ba-146, the error is from your transcription of the data table. The difference between the mass number $A$ and the mass in daltons is smaller than about 0.1 daltons for every known nuclide. Other data sources  tabulate these "mass excesses" directly, so you have $\Delta_{^{239}\rm Pu} = 0.05216\rm \ Da$ rather than $m _{^{239}\rm Pu} = 239.05216\rm \ Da$. The [Nuclear Wallet Cards](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/nudat3/indx_sigma.jsp) even tabulate the mass excesses in energy units, saving you a conversion.